# What is a Non Static Variable and how do I fix them

Tags: java

I have a homework assignment where I am supposed to simulate the roll of a dice using math.random() and changing it to an int. I have a single file with 2 classes and am attempting to make an object. My code compiles with the run time error "error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context." Any Idea what is happening.

I have changed the value of "value" to an integer and successfully ran the code. No other changes have come to mind yet.

```
public class DieTester_5AlastiCorrigan {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // New object myDie. 
        Die myDie = new Die();
        System.out.println(myDie.roll());
        System.out.println(myDie.getValue());
    }

    // Creates a new Die Class 
    class Die{
        private String value;

        public Die( int dieRoll ) {
            value = "" + dieRoll;

        }

        // Roll Method chooses random number between 1 - 7 and makes it    an int. 
        public int roll() {
            int max = 6;
            int min = 1;
            int range = max + 1;

            int dieRoll = (int)Math.random()*range;
            //dieRoll = (int)dieRoll;
            return dieRoll;
        }
        // getValue Method returns final value of "value". 
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }


}
```

Expect the console to print out a number 1 <= x < 7 as an integer.

Error message: `error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        Die myDie = new Die();
                    ^`

Comment: in your constructor you have a parameter...?

Comment: Die myDie = new Die(10); i think you need to pass an integer parameter to the constructor. can't create Die() without parameters

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you'll also need to mark your nested class as static.
`static class Die { ... }`

Comment: @JSextonn Is correct for one easy solution; you could also move the class to another file named `Die.java`; *almost any problem that can't be solved with a bigger hammer, can be solved with a welding torch*.

Comment: While the duplicate talks about variables, it's still relevant in your case. `static class Die` fixes your issue.

Comment: You should move your class to a separate file (`Die.java`).

Comment: make Die class static.

Comment: I am required to turn in one file, so have a separate class file voids the instructions. Thanks though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how your `Die` class is inside your `DieTester_5AlastiCorrigan` class. That makes it an *non-static* inner class. You would need an instance of `DieTester_5AlastiCorrigan` to create an instance of `Die`. So to fix this, simply move `Die` to the top level, like this:

```
class DieTester_5AlastiCorrigan {
    ...
}

class Die {
    ...
}
```

Or add a `static` modifier:

```
class DieTester_5AlastiCorrigan {
    ...

    static class Die {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, there are still a few mistakes in your code. `Die` has a constructor that takes an `int`, but when you are creating a `Die`, `Die myDie = new Die();`, you are not passing an `int` to the constructor. I suggest that you add a parameterless constructor:

```
public Die() {
    this(1);
}
```

Also, `value` should not be of type `String`. It should be an `int`, and judging from your usage, `roll` should change the value of `value` instead of returning the die roll.

Answer (score 0):

class Die is an instance variable of class DieTester_5AlastiCorrigan , which means you can only create a Die instance with a DieTester_5AlastiCorrigan instance.
This code should run:

```
DieTester_5AlastiCorrigan outerObject = new DieTester_5AlastiCorrigan();
DieTester_5AlastiCorrigan.Die myDie = outerObject.new Die();
```

Comment: but why create an outer Object instance that has no functionality at all? that is at most a workaround, not a solution

Comment: because i thought that the way you wanted, if you dont want to create outer object then just declare Die as static, like this : static class Die {..

Comment: 1) I am not the author of the question; 2) it is not a matter of wanting or not; programming just to avoid compilation errors will not work very well on bigger (real) projects - *if your cars door is not closing correctly, the solution is not just removing the door* 3) die `Die` constructor expects an argument, but that would be the next error (Why not just move the `Die` class outside the tester class, if not moving to an own file? It does not need, by given coe, to be a nested class at all)

Comment: i guess this is just a small test, and he just forgot to declare the inner class as static